# How to show data in custom tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table looks like below structure.

```
user_id  Payment_status
1          Pending
2          Success
3          Failed
```

I have created sample example, on hover of user id I am getting user info which I need to show on tooltip, I need a styled tooltip that looks like bootstrap tooltip with data placement top. Please see this example and [TryHere](http://jsfiddle.net/3bLh187q/)

If you see in console I am getting data of hovered user, I just need to show this data like tooltip and on hover out I need to hide. Please check fiddle and open console. You will get it. Ask me if any info missing.

Here is JS code

```
var orders=[
{id: 1, first_name: "Sud", last_name: "D", phone: "45687889", email: "sud@peace.org"},
{id: 2, first_name: "Mat", last_name: "D", phone: "123456789", email: "mat@peace.org"},
{id: 3, first_name: "Suraj", last_name: "D", phone: "321145789", email: "suraj@peace.org"}
];

$('.user_id').hover(function(){
console.log('hi'+$(this).text());
var current_id=$(this).text();
                for (var i =0;i<=orders.length - 1; i++) {
                    if (orders[i].id==current_id) {
                        console.log('hi'+orders[i].first_name+'<br>'+orders[i].last_name+'<br>'+orders[i].email);
                    };
                };
})
```

Html code

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>user_id</th>
      <th>Payment Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><a class="user_id"  href="">1</a></td>
      <td>Success</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><a class="user_id" href="">2</a></td>
      <td>Failed</td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
      <td><a class="user_id" href="">3</a></td>
      <td>Pending</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you want to make the ajax call and show its data in a _tooltip_ on same hover event?

Comment: No I have made everything, just tell me how to append data to tooltip, Updated my question please check now, just want data to be showed in tooltip

Comment: You need to use the `title` attribute like `<a href="#" title = "your title">1<a>`.

Comment: I cant pass directly to title, That data is coming from ajax request, I am getting data of that user only on user hovers. If pass data to title there are so many records which will have this title. so only showing hovered user info

Comment: You can access it via script and set the data dynamically. `$(this)` will refer to the element you are hovering on. `$(this).attr('title', data);`, something like this?!

Comment: Yeah but I want custom title with some styles, it should look like bootstrap tooltip with data-placement:top, and most important it should have support break, say sud<br>email<br>phone. Title is not supporting br

Answer (score 1):

if you add this line to your javascript you can see the tooltip

```
 $('.user_id').hover(function(){
console.log('hi'+$(this).text());
var current_id=$(this).text();
                for (var i =0;i<=orders.length - 1; i++) {
                    if (orders[i].id==current_id) {
                                  console.log('hi'+orders[i].first_name+'<br>'+orders[i].last_name+'<br>'+orders[i].email);
                     $(this).attr('title','hi'+orders[i].first_name+'<br>'+orders[i].last_name+'<br>'      +orders[i].email);
                    };
                };
})
```

Comment: Yeah I tried this, it works can you style this as per bootstrap tooltip? which will have data-placement top?? and it should support <br>

Comment: may you show a graphic example about your final goal?

Comment: If you see in my question I have clearly added this "I need a styled tooltip that looks like bootstrap tooltip with data placement top." and your answer is correct, I also tried this but title not supports breaks. and it should look like styled tooltip

Comment: try this $(this).attr('title','hi'+orders[i].first_name+'\n'+orders[i].last_name+'\n'      +orders[i].email);

Comment: can you see this fiddle please? I want tooltip like this http://jsfiddle.net/shail/vstlu/2/

Comment: Thanks you deserve one upvote from me, can you please tell me how to style this like in fiddle i sent above

Comment: I dont know why bootstrap tooltip is now working in my case, I have added each attr and initialized it still it is not working

Comment: sorry but you can't customize the style because it depend by the browser used. Maybe you have to consider to change approach like this http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/11/how-to-create-a-simple-css3-tooltip/

Answer (score 0):

I use this tooltip code:

```
function ExtractorTooltip() {
    //**  Tooltip Class  **//

    this.tooltip = null;
    this.tooltipTextContainer = null;

}
ExtractorTooltip.prototype = {


    initToolTip: function(_id, _width, _height, _position, _backgroundColor, _borderRadious, _textColor, _fontFamily, _fontSize, _margin, _padding) {
        //Create div element

        this.tooltip = $('<div></div>').attr('id', _id).css({
            width: _width,
            height: _height,
            position: _position,
            background: _backgroundColor,
            borderRadius: _borderRadious + 'px',
            MozBorderRadius: _borderRadious + 'px',
            margin: _margin + 'px',
            padding: _padding + 'px',
            'z-index': 2147483600
        }).appendTo('body');

        this.tooltipTextContainer = $('<span></span>').css({
            fontFamily: _fontFamily.toString(),
            fontSize: _fontSize + 'px',
            color: _textColor
        }).appendTo(this.tooltip);        

        this.hide();
    },
    addTooltipTo: function(_container) {
var self=this;
                  _container.addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) {
                this.show(event.target.getAttribute('filter'));

            $(document).on('mousemove.tooltip', function(ev) {
                self.tooltip.css({
                    left: ev.pageX + 'px',
                    top: ev.pageY + 'px'
                });

            });
        }.bind(this), false);

        _container.addEventListener('mouseout', function(event) {
            this.hide();          
            $(document).off('mousemove.tooltip');
        }.bind(this), false);
        _container.style.border = '3px solid rgb(255,0,0)';
    },
    show: function(_text) {
        this.tooltip.css('display', 'inline');
        this.tooltipTextContainer.text(_text);

    },
    hide: function() {
        this.tooltip.css({
            display: 'none',
            left: 0 + 'px',
            top: 0 + 'px'
        });

    },

};
```

You can call it like:

```
var extractorTooltip = new ExtractorTooltip();   
extractorTooltip.initToolTip('tooltip', 'auto', 20, 'absolute', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)', 10, '#ffffff', 'helvetica', 16, 12, 12);
        }
 $image.attr('filters', 'Filter data:' + filterDescription);
  self.extractorTooltip.addTooltipTo($image.get(0));
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Lwaz2ap4/4/)

Comment: This is prototype class of tooltip, and the example of call it. You can customize this code for you needs

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/shail/vstlu/2/ see the first example, in which tooltip is at top, but I want that without bootstrap.